# Como mudar a posição do owl-nav no Owl.Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, owl-carousel

Estou usando o Owl.Carousel e estou quebrando a cabeça com o posicionamento das setas do NAV, preciso que ao invés de estar abaixo dos artigos ele fique acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ou como fazer  para botões criados em algum canto da página movimentarem como o nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc pode criar um pequeno CSS, duas linhas apenas, para corrigir isso.

Primeiro vc da display flex no *container*, e depois alinhas as `div` em uma coluna inversa com `flex-direction: column-reverse !important;` Assim a ordem dos elemento fica "invertida" começando de baixo para cima, dessa forma primeiro veem as bolinhas, depois setas e depois as imagens.

Veja como fica no exemplo. *(se não quiser as bolinhas deixei o CSS comentado abaixo)*

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}

/* se não quiser as bolinhas descomente o css abaixo */
/* .owl-dots {
display: none;
} */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: É possível colocar botões em uma div, e colocar o comando do NAV nos meus botões?

Comment: @Arthur74 é possível sim! Só vou te pedir para vc abrir uma Nova Pergunta, pq a explicação é um pouco complexa e vou precisar de te dar alguns detalhes etc. Fazer a edição nessa pergunta que já foi respondida e colocar essas informações só ia confundir as coisas. Então vamos manter as coisas separadas beleza, cria a pergunta lá e me fala que eu te passo os detalhes que vc vai precisar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329179/atribuir-comando-do-nav-em-botões-owl-carousel