# Atribuir comando do NAV em botões - Owl.Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos, owl-carousel

Gostaria de entender como eu puxo o comando dos NAV's do Owl.Carousel para meus botões ja estilizados em uma div separada.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
 dots:false,
})
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 0 11px;*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}
#caixas{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 .caixa1{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div id="caixas">
 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   
   <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    
    
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Imagens</a>
    <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="position_btcx" id="navContainer">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    
   </nav>
   
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pelo visto já deu certo ai, nem deu tempo de responder rss. Boa sorte com o projeto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode disparar os eventos `prev.owl.carousel` e `next.owl.carousel` ao clicar nos botões. Basta atribuir aos dois botões um evento `click` e disparar os eventos do Owl Carousel acima de acordo com o botão clicado.

Para ficar mais elegante, crie o evento dos botões dentro do callback `onInitialized` do componente. O `onInitialized` dispara quando o plugin tiver sido inicializado. (**[Documentação do componente](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)**)

Seu código deve ficar desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); // cria uma váriável para o elemento
   owl.owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true,
      dots:false,
      onInitialized: function(){
         $("#navContainer .button_cx") // seleciona os botões
         .click(function(){
            var idx = $(this).parent().children().index(this); // pega o índice do botão clicado
            owl.trigger( (idx == 1 ? 'next' : 'prev') + '.owl.carousel'); // atribui o evento ao devido botão
         });
      }
   });
});
```

**Vamos ver funcionando:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); // cria uma váriável para o elemento
   owl.owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true,
      dots:false,
      onInitialized: function(){
         $("#navContainer .button_cx") // seleciona os botões
         .click(function(){
            var idx = $(this).parent().children().index(this); // pega o índice do botão clicado
            owl.trigger( (idx == 1 ? 'next' : 'prev') + '.owl.carousel'); // atribui o evento ao devido botão
         });
      }
   });
});
```

```css
/*apenas para exemplo*/ .item { height: 30px; background: red !important; }

* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 0 11px;*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}
#caixas{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 .caixa1{
  /*margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;*/
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="caixas">
 <div class="caixa1">
  <div class="menu_horizontal">
   
   <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    
    
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
     <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Imagens</a>
    <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="position_btcx" id="navContainer">
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
     <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    
   </nav>
   
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt=""></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito! confesso que não tinha visto essa documentação inteira.