# Slide owl carousel2 com background image

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

Preciso fazer a imagem fundo do slide trocar e o conteúdo deve ser statico como na imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] acredito que fazendo com `background-image` de para fazer mais não sei como alguém sabe como me ajudar

Comment: Quantas imagens quer ficar trocando? Qual o efeito de transição que imaginou? Fade ou slide pro lado? Eh obrigatório ser com background ou pode ser com a tag img?

Comment: @hugocsl
acredito que umas 4 o efeito pode ser fade pode ser com img mais desde que o input não saia de la quando o slide rodar o input tem que ficar sempre lá

Comment: Vou montar um exemplo básico pra vc com 4 img, fade e o menu e o input "por cima". E as setinha para passar as imagens é obrigatório ou pode ficar rodando automaticamente?

Comment: @hugocsl as setinhas são obrigatórias obrigado pela ajuda ficarei no aguardo

Comment: Cara eu ia bolar uma resposta, mas acho que sua pergunta está bem próxima disso, se esse link não resolver seu problema me fala: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334204/transi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-autom%C3%A1tica-de-imagens-no-slider-com-css#comment676065_334204

Comment: @hugocsl
Então só que como está com a img e é uma lista se eu colocar meu form dentro ele passa junto com o slide  nao da para fazer com owl carousel?

Comment: Cara acho que da sim, amanha te monto um exemplo com owl  caroucel  vcs esta usando bootstrap?

Comment: @hugocsl sim estou usando Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

Cara fiz esse exemplo tentando usar ao máximo os componentes padrão do Bootstrap já que vc falou que está usando ele. Também fiz o carrocel com o Owl Caroucel como vc havia falado que está usando.

Tive que colocar alguns elemento com `position:absolute` para poder posicionar sobre o `slider`, porém ficou todo 100% responsivo e funcionando. A `navbar` original do Bootstrap funciona sem problemas assim como o `slider`

Não usei os nav buttons originais do Owl Carousel, usei um modelo customizado para fazer a navegação dos slides ([aqui tem o código que usei de base](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329179/atribuir-comando-do-nav-em-bot%C3%B5es-owl-carousel))

Foi preciso definir uma altura pro carrocel, mas vc pode mudar isso a vontade que a imagem sempre vai ocupar toda a extensão da tela sem deformar, pois usei `object-fit`

A parte responsiva fica por conta do próprio Grid do Bootstrap que foi usado tranquilamente para ajustar o conteúdo nos *containers*.

Veja como ficou o modelo, teste também em "Página toda" para ver como fica:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

  <style>

.owl-carousel .item{
  height: 300px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.jumbotron-fluid-topo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.container-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.btn-meio {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.container-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.container-nav .btns {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.container-nav .btns:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-fluid-topo">

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placecage.com/360/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placecage.com/360/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placecage.com/360/200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placecage.com/360/200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid container-input">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-meio" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
              </div>
              <button class="btn" type="button"></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid container-nav">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end" id="navs">
            <div class="btns"></div>
            <div class="btns"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        items: 1,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        onInitialized: function () {
          $("#navs .btns")
            .click(function () {
              var navBtn = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
              owl.trigger((navBtn == 1 ? 'next' : 'prev') + '.owl.carousel');
            });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```